# Djangoのインストールについて

Tags: python, django

djangoをインストールし、データベースのセットアップをしていたところ、次のようなエラーが出ました。
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。

sqliteがインストールされていないということかと思い、インストールしてみましたが、同様のエラーが出てきてしまいした。解決法をご教授いただきたいです。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[sqlite3 import * ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.](https://bugs.python.org/issue43201), [pythonにsqlite3が無いと怒られる](https://yoshida-ahiru.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/13/020007), [Unable to import sqlite3 using Anaconda Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54876404/9014308), ["ImportError: DLL load failed" in PyCharm w/ conda: how to automatically import conda's PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54766467/9014308)

Comment: CPythonからダウンロードしてきたインストーラでインストールしたPython環境だと標準で入っているものなので、ファイルが消えたなどで環境が壊れたことを疑います。どこから入手した、どのPythonをどうやってインストールしたのか、がないと回答は誰もできないかと思います。

Comment: pathを追加することでこのエラーは出なくなったんですが、次のエラーが出るようになってしました。              　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is

Comment: そのキーワードで検索するとDjangoではなくSelenium ChromeDriver関連の記事が見つかります。直接はDjangoとは関連の無い事象なのでは？ もしくは元々の環境設定や各種インストールが上手くいっていないので、次から次へとモグラたたきのように問題が発生するとか？ どこか貴方の環境に合致したインストール・セットアップを解説した記事・書籍などを探して、それに従った作業を行うことを考えてみてはどうでしょう？ [Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67501093/9014308), [Getting a Passthrough is not supported GL is disabled, even though it is enabled; unable to run web scraping python script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68146989/9014308)

Comment: すいません。初めのコマンドにpythonを書き加えることでエラーが消えました。丁寧な回答ありがとうございました！